# Using encodeURI() vs. escape() for utf-8 strings in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, unicode, utf-8, escaping, encode

I am handling utf-8 strings in JavaScript and need to escape them.

Both escape() / unescape() and encodeURI() / decodeURI() work in my browser.

**escape()**

```
> var hello = "안녕하세요"
> var hello_escaped = escape(hello)
> hello_escaped
  "%uC548%uB155%uD558%uC138%uC694"
> var hello_unescaped = unescape(hello_escaped)
> hello_unescaped
  "안녕하세요"
```

**encodeURI()**

```
> var hello = "안녕하세요"    
> var hello_encoded = encodeURI(hello)
> hello_encoded
  "%EC%95%88%EB%85%95%ED%95%98%EC%84%B8%EC%9A%94"
> var hello_decoded = decodeURI(hello_encoded)
> hello_decoded
  "안녕하세요"
```

However, [Mozilla says that escape() is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape).

Although encodeURI() and decodeURI() work with the above utf-8 string, the docs (as well as the function names themselves) tell me that these methods are for URIs; I do not see utf-8 strings mentioned anywhere.

Simply put, is it okay to use encodeURI() and decodeURI() for utf-8 strings?

Comment: yes, those are fine; it's escape() that can't do UTF correctly. that said, you might want to use encodeURIComponent(), i see it a lot more than "just" encodeURI()

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Functions/encodeURIComponent

Comment: `encodeURI()` without UTF-8 and `escape()` with UTF-8

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Hi!**

When it comes to `escape` and `unescape`, I live by two rules:

1. Avoid them when you easily can.
2. Otherwise, use them.

#### Avoiding them when you easily can:

As mentioned in the question, both `escape` and `unescape` have been deprecated. In general, one should avoid using deprecated functions.

So, if `encodeURIComponent` or `encodeURI` does the trick for you, you should use that instead of `escape`.

#### Using them when you can't easily avoid them:

Browsers will, as far as possible, strive to achieve backwards compatibility. All major browsers have already implemented `escape` and `unescape`; why would they un-implement them?

Browsers would have to redefine `escape`and `unescape` if the new specification requires them to do so. But wait! The people who write specifications are quite smart. They too, are interested in not breaking backwards compatibility!

I realize that the above argument is weak. But trust me, ... when it comes to browsers, deprecated stuff works. This even includes deprecated HTML tags like `<xmp>` and `<center>`.

#### Using `escape` and `unescape`:

So naturally, the next question is, when would one use `escape` or `unescape`?

Recently, while working on [CloudBrave](https://www.cloudbrave.com/), I had to deal with `utf8`, `latin1` and inter-conversions.

After reading a bunch of blog posts, I realized how simple this was:

```
var utf8_to_latin1 = function (s) {
    return unescape(encodeURIComponent(s));
};
var latin1_to_utf8 = function (s) {
    return decodeURIComponent(escape(s));
};
```

These inter-conversions, without using `escape` and `unescape` are rather involved. By not avoiding `escape` and `unescape`, life becomes simpler.

**Hope this helps.**

Comment: Thank you.  
return decodeURIComponent(escape(s));
Worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

*It is **never** okay to use `encodeURI()` or `encodeURIComponent()`.*  Let's try it out:

```js
console.log(encodeURIComponent('@#*'));
```

Input: `@#*`.  Output: `%40%23*`.  Wait, so, what exactly happened to the `*` character?  Why wasn't that converted?  Imagine this: You ask a user what file to delete and their response is `*`.  Server-side, you convert that using `encodeURIComponent()` and then run `rm *`.  Well, got news for you: [using `encodeURIComponent()` means you just deleted all files.](https://askubuntu.com/q/956724/1192990)

Use [`fixedEncodeURI()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI), when trying to encode a complete URL (i.e., all of `example.com?arg=val`), as defined and further explained at the [**MDN encodeURI() Documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI)...

> ```
> function fixedEncodeURI(str) {
>    return encodeURI(str).replace(/%5B/g, '[').replace(/%5D/g, ']');
> }
> ```

Or, you may need to use use [`fixedEncodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent), when trying to encode part of a URL (i.e., the `arg` or the `val` in `example.com?arg=val`), as defined and further explained at the [**MDN encodeURIComponent() Documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)...

> ```
> function fixedEncodeURIComponent(str) {
>  return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/[!'()*]/g, function(c) {
>    return '%' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
>  });
> }
> ```

If you are unable to distinguish them based on the above description, I always like to simplify it with:

- `fixedEncodeURI()` : ***will not*** encode `+@?=:#;,$&` to their http-encoded equivalents (as `&` and `+` are common URL operators)
- `fixedEncodeURIComponent()` ***will*** encode `+@?=:#;,$&` to their http-encoded equivalents.

Comment: Your example why to avoid this command is very constructed. "Server-side, you convert that using encodeURIComponent() and then run rm *".
Why should anyone call that javascript command on the server and then execute a system command with this escaped string?
The purpose of encodeURIComponent is the encoding of an URI component (as the name says) and not encoding command line arguments.

Without any better example your objections are just unnecessary input for people with the same question as the person who asked this. :-/

Answer (score 1):

> Mozilla says that escape() is deprecated.

Yes, you should avoid both `escape()` and `unescape()`

---

> Simply put, is it okay to use encodeURI() and decodeURI() for utf-8 strings?

Yes, but depending on the form of your input and the required form of your output you may need some extra work.

From your question I assume you have a JavaScript string and you want to convert encoding to UTF-8 and finally store the string in some escaped form.

First of all it's important to note that JavaScript strings enconding is UCS-2, similar to UTF-16, different from UTF-8.

See: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-encoding

`encodeURIComponent()` is good for the job as turns the UCS-2 JavaScript string into UTF-8 and escapes it in the form a sequence of `%nn` substrings where each `nn` is the two hex digits of each byte.

However `encodeURIComponent()` does not escape letters, digits and few other characters in the ASCII range. But this is easy to fix.

For example, if you want to turn a JavaScript string into an array of numbers representing the bytes of the original string UTF-8 encoded you may use this function:

```
//
// Convert JavaScript UCS2 string to array of bytes representing the string UTF8 encoded
//

function StringUTF8AsBytesArrayFromString( s )
{
    var i,
        n,
        u;

    u = [];
    s = encodeURIComponent( s );

    n = s.length;
    for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        if( s.charAt( i ) == '%' )
        {
            u.push( parseInt( s.substring( i + 1, i + 3 ), 16 ) );
            i += 2;
        }
        else
        {
            u.push( s.charCodeAt( i ) );
        }
    }

    return u;
}
```

If you want to turn the string in its hexadecimal representation:

```
//
// Convert JavaScript UCS2 string to hex string representing the bytes of the string UTF8 encoded
//

function StringUTF8AsHexFromString( s )
{
    var u,
        i,
        n,
        s;

    u = StringUTF8AsBytesArrayFromString( s );
    n = u.length;
    s = '';    

    for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        s += ( u[ i ] < 16 ? '0' : '' ) + u[ i ].toString( 16 );
    }

    return s;
}
```

If you change the line in the for loop into

`s += '%' + ( u[ i ] < 16 ? '0' : '' ) + u[ i ].toString( 16 );`

(adding the `%` sign before each hex digit)

The resulting escaped string (UTF-8 encoded) may be turned back into a JavaScript UCS-2 string with `decodeURIComponent()`

Comment: see also String.prototype.codePointAt() and String.fromCharCode() for utf-8 compatible single character conversion.

Comment: Correction - String.fromCodePoint();

Comment: I wanted to provide a solition that works both on legacy browsers (whereString.fromCodePoint is not available), current browsers and future browsers that may drop escape/unescape