# Calculate Git file blob SHA (handle emojis etc.)

Tags: git, byte, github-api, endianness

I am pushing files to GitHub using the javascript API. I'd like to avoid using up an API call (toward rate limit) if the file on GitHub is unchanged. Hitting the tree API to get the file's sha doesn't seem to count against rate limit, so I figure a good strategy is to (a) calculate the sha of the file that will be uploaded using javascript and (b) compare it with the sha of the existing file at GitHub. This strategy works with plain-text files. But the calculation causes a mismatch when emojis are involved.

I have a simple repo [here](https://github.com/vsjc91/sospike/tree/main).

I created a contents/read-write (this repo only) personal-access-token that you can use to run the code directly (e.g. from the javascript console window).

The console output results in the simple letter "a" file having a sha of '2e65efe2a145dda7ee51d1741299f848e5bf752e' as reported by GitHub and also via javascript. In my tests, it also works with json files containing line-breaks etc. But the sha no longer matches once emojis are involved.

If you have ideas on how to calculate the sha locally when emojis / special characters are involved, I'll be grateful. Thanks!

```
var _repo = 'sospike';
var _owner = 'vsjc91';

var _lettera = 'a';
var _emoji = '';

// I created a contents/read-write (this repo only) personal-access-token that you can use:
var _auth = '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';

// stackoverflow.com/questions/73419876/javascript-replace-all-emoji-in-a-string-to-unicode-and-back
// also read re "deprecated" but "ok for this use case"
// stackoverflow.com/questions/30631927/converting-to-base64-in-javascript-without-deprecated-escape-call
const encodeTextEmojis = function(plainText) {
  return unescape(encodeURIComponent(plainText));
}

const decodeBase64Emojis = function(b64) {
  return decodeURIComponent(escape(b64));
}

// stackoverflow.com/questions/73419876/javascript-replace-all-emoji-in-a-string-to-unicode-and-back
const toBase64 = function(str, adjustEmojis) {
  if (adjustEmojis == true) {
    str = encodeTextEmojis(str);
  }
  return btoa(str);
}

const fromBase64 = function(b64, adjustEmojis) {
  if (adjustEmojis == true) {
    b64 = decodeBase64Emojis(b64);
  }
  return atob(b64);
}

const buildHeaders = function() {
  return {
        Accept: 'application/vnd.github+json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${_auth}`
      }
}

const tryGetFileResponse = async function(url, headers) {
  const request = { method: "GET", headers: headers };
  try {
    return await fetch(url, request);
  }
  catch {
    // it's ok if the file isn't there
    return null;
  }
}

const getExistingSha = async function(fileName) {
  const url = `https://api.github.com/repos/${_owner}/${_repo}/git/trees/main:?cacheBreaker=${Date.now()}`;
  const headers = buildHeaders();
  const response = await tryGetFileResponse(url, headers);
  if (!response) { return null; }
  const tree = await response.json();
  if (!tree || !tree.tree) { return null; }
  const files = tree.tree;
  
  const file = files.find(function(f) {
    return f.path && f.path.toLowerCase() == fileName.toLowerCase();
  });
  
  if (!file) { return null; }
  console.log('github reported length for ' + fileName + ' of ' + file.size);
  return file.sha;
}

const upload = async function(path, content) {
  const commitMsg = 'testing';
  const encodedContent = toBase64(content, true);

  const existingSha = await getExistingSha(path, content);
  console.log('existing sha: ' + existingSha);

  const putFileBody = { message: commitMsg, content: encodedContent };
  if (existingSha) {
    putFileBody.sha = existingSha;
  }

  await (await fetch(
    `https://api.github.com/repos/${_owner}/${_repo}/contents/${path}`,
    {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: buildHeaders(),
      body: JSON.stringify(putFileBody),
    }
  )).json();
}

/****************************************/
// calculate sha from javascript
/****************************************/

const utf8ByteLen = function(str) {
  if (!str || str.length == 0) { return 0; }
  const inputBytes = new TextEncoder().encode(str);
  return inputBytes.length;
}
  
// stackoverflow.com/a/40031979/9014097
const buf2hex = function (buffer) { // buffer is an ArrayBuffer
  return Array.prototype.map.call(new Uint8Array(buffer), x => ('00' + x.toString(16)).slice(-2)).join('');
}
  
// stackoverflow.com/questions/63736585/why-does-crypto-subtle-digest-return-an-empty-object
const calcSha1 = async function(str) {
  if (!str || str.length == 0) { return null; }
  const inputBytes = new TextEncoder().encode(str);
  const hashBytes = await window.crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-1', inputBytes);
  const hashedStr = buf2hex(hashBytes);
  return hashedStr;
}
  
// stackoverflow.com/questions/7225313/how-does-git-compute-file-hashes?rq=3
const calcGithubTextContentSha = async function(text) {
  const adjText = encodeTextEmojis(text);
  const len = utf8ByteLen(text);
  const data = `blob ${len}\0${adjText}`;
  const sha = calcSha1(data);
  return sha;
}

/****************************************/
// run the test
/****************************************/

console.log('A text file created manually with just "a" at github.com has:')
const sha_manual = await getExistingSha('plain_typed.txt');
console.log('that sha is: ' + sha_manual);

console.log('Upload a file containing just "a" to github via code and fetch back its sha:')
await upload('plain.txt', _lettera);
const sha = await getExistingSha('plain.txt');
console.log('pushed "a" file with sha: ' + sha);

console.log('Compare vs. calculate from javascript');
const sha_js = await calcGithubTextContentSha(_lettera);
console.log('js sha for "a" file: ' + sha_js);

console.log('Now try an emoji character');
await upload('emoji.txt', _emoji);
const sha_emoji = await getExistingSha('emoji.txt');
console.log('github emoji sha: ' + sha_emoji);

const sha_emoji_js = await calcGithubTextContentSha(_emoji);
console.log('js emoji sha: ' + sha_emoji_js);
```

(A possible clue? - I notice that the file size a file just containing the letter "a" is either 1 or 2, depending on whether it's edited using GitHub.com manually vs. pushed using this code).

Here is the log output:

```
A text file created manually with just "a" at github.com has:
github reported length for plain_typed.txt of 2
that sha is: 78981922613b2afb6025042ff6bd878ac1994e85

Upload a file containing just "a" to github via code and fetch back its sha:
github reported length for plain.txt of 1
existing sha: 2e65efe2a145dda7ee51d1741299f848e5bf752e
github reported length for plain.txt of 1
pushed "a" file with sha: 2e65efe2a145dda7ee51d1741299f848e5bf752e

Compare vs. calculate from javascript
js sha for "a" file: 2e65efe2a145dda7ee51d1741299f848e5bf752e

Now try an emoji character
github reported length for emoji.txt of 4
existing sha: 9ad8dd6d25e074eca9e19e06458bb9e7a314a875
github reported length for emoji.txt of 4
github emoji sha: 9ad8dd6d25e074eca9e19e06458bb9e7a314a875
js emoji sha: 553045c77ac300d4907c43bf0de77326ec610474
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few apparent issues:

The `encodeTextEmojis` and `decodeBase64Emojis` functions use [`unescape`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape) and [`escape`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape) respectively. These functions are not recommended for handling multibyte characters like emojis. Additionally, these methods are deprecated.
And since the `toBase64` and `fromBase64` functions call the aforementioned encoding and decoding functions, that could lead to incorrect handling of emojis.
In the `calcGithubTextContentSha` function, the `encodeTextEmojis` function is called which could potentially alter the text, leading to a different SHA-1 hash than expected.

The difference in file size reported by GitHub for manually created files versus programmatically uploaded files could be a sign of an encoding discrepancy, although it is not directly reflected in the code. It could also be an eol (end of line character) added in one environment and not the other.

Using a [TextEncoder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder) is safer:

Note: this is for the SHA1 of a file, not the SHA1 you need on GitHub, which represents the SHA1 of the commit, and that include more than the content of a file, but:

- The source tree of the commit (which unravels to all the subtrees and blobs)
- The parent commit sha1
- The author info
- The committer info (those can be different!)
- The commit message

---

> This gets me close. However, if I change the emoji test text to 'tests ' then it seems to require escape/unescape for the upload (for the calculation code I've used yours exactly).
>
> Without escape/unescape on the upload I create a file with 'tests%20%F0%9F%8C%BB'. I take some comfort in "[Converting to Base64 in JavaScript without Deprecated 'Escape' call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30631927/6309)". Or do you have a better suggestion for the upload?

The encoding issue you are experiencing when uploading text with emojis and spaces is due to URL encoding happening somewhere in the process. When you see `%20` replacing spaces, and `%F0%9F%8C%BB` representing the emoji, that is URL encoding at play.

In JavaScript, the [`fetch` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) along with [`btoa` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/btoa) for Base64 encoding should handle UTF-8 characters correctly without needing to escape/unescape them. However, if you find that URL encoding is happening and altering your text, you may need to decode it back to its original form before uploading.

The stack overflow post you linked suggests a workaround using `unescape` and `encodeURIComponent`, but `unescape` is a deprecated function and not recommended.

Again, using `TextEncoder`, `TextDecoder`, and `fetch` should be safer:

```js
// Function to encode text to Base64, updated to handle potential overflows for large files.
const textToBase64 = function(text) {
    let encoder = new TextEncoder();
    let data = encoder.encode(text);
    let base64 = btoa([].reduce.call(new Uint8Array(data), function(p, c) {
        return p + String.fromCharCode(c);
    }, ''));
    return base64;
};

// Function to decode Base64 to text
const base64ToText = function(base64) {
  let binaryString = atob(base64);
  let bytes = new Uint8Array(binaryString.length);
  for (let i = 0; i < binaryString.length; i++) {
    bytes[i] = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  let decoder = new TextDecoder();
  return decoder.decode(bytes);
};

// Your upload function
const upload = async function(path, content) {
  const commitMsg = 'testing';
  const encodedContent = textToBase64(content);  // using the new textToBase64 function

  const existingSha = await getExistingSha(path, content);
  console.log('existing sha: ' + existingSha);

  const putFileBody = { message: commitMsg, content: encodedContent };
  if (existingSha) {
    putFileBody.sha = existingSha;
  }

  await (await fetch(
    `https://api.github.com/repos/${_owner}/${_repo}/contents/${path}`,
    {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: buildHeaders(),
      body: JSON.stringify(putFileBody),
    }
  )).json();
};

// Rest of your code
```

`textToBase64` function is updated to handle UTF-8 encoding properly when converting text to Base64.
As noted by [the OP Vince](https://stackoverflow.com/users/197760/vince) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77290492/calculate-git-file-blob-sha-handle-emojis-etc/77299870#comment136285034_77299870), and the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9267899/arraybuffer-to-base64-encoded-string/11562550#comment55137593_11562550) from [laggingreflex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1266650/laggingreflex), in the updated `textToBase64` function, the `btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(data)))` line has been replaced with `btoa([].reduce.call(new Uint8Array(data), function(p, c) { return p + String.fromCharCode(c); }, ''))`. That change aims to handle larger files by building the string in a way that avoids potential overflow issues.

`base64ToText` function is added to handle decoding of Base64 to text, if needed.
`upload` function now uses `textToBase64` to encode the content to Base64, which should correctly handle emojis and other special characters without URL encoding them.

When you upload text containing emojis and spaces using the `upload` function, it should no longer result in URL-encoded text on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks. This gets me close. However, if I change the emoji test text to 'tests ' then it seems to require escape/unescape for the upload (for the calculation code I've used yours exactly). Without escape/unescape on the upload I create a file with 'tests%20%F0%9F%8C%BB'. I take some comfort in stackoverflow.com/questions/30631927/converting-to-base64-in-javascript-without-deprecated-escape-call. Or do you have a better suggestion for the upload? Thanks.

Comment: @Vince I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you. I made a small change to handle an overflow incurred for large files. Based on the comment by laggingreflex [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9267899/arraybuffer-to-base64-encoded-string/11562550#11562550](here). 

let base64 = btoa([].reduce.call(new Uint8Array(bufferArray),function(p,c){return p+String.fromCharCode(c)},''));

Comment: @Vince Great, well done! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility. I have updated the code accordingly, and cleaned up the answer to keep only one version of the code.